# MixMonitor applied to every extention in a context

Tags: asterisk, voip, freepbx

I'm trying to setup call recording in Asterisk applied to a whole context.

**extensions.conf** looks like this:

`[office]
  exten => _068.,1,Dial(SIP/sip_trunk_1/${EXTEN})
  exten => _073.,1,Dial(SIP/sip_trunk_1/${EXTEN})
  exten => _099.,1,Dial(SIP/sip_trunk_1/${EXTEN})`

I've tried to do something like this:

`[office]
  exten => s,1,Set(filename=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y/%m/%d/%H_%M_%S)})
  exten => s,2,MixMonitor(${filename}.wav, b)
  exten => _068.,1,Dial(SIP/sip_trunk_1/${EXTEN})
  exten => _073.,1,Dial(SIP/sip_trunk_2/${EXTEN})
  exten => _099.,1,Dial(SIP/sip_trunk_3/${EXTEN})
  exten => h,1,StopMixMonitor()`

But it doesn't work, `MixMonitor` never starts.

The only way it works is by setting up `MixMonitor` separately for every single extention.

Is there any way to specify one global `MixMonitor` globally? Because I have a lot of extentions, and specifying separate recorder for each of them will mess up my configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to adjust your contexts slightly. Create a [office-start] context. And do something like this:

[office-start]

exten => _X.,1,Set(Filename=XYZ)

exten => _X.,n,MixMonitor()

exten => _X.,n,Goto(office,${exten},1)

Then set the context on your sip peers to office-start